# Deserialise JSON message of two types

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I try to consume web service returning JSON messages. Each method returns relevant JSON message (typically an array) or JSON error message (not an array).

Examples of UserList and Error messages:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "login":"john1",
      "full_name":"John Smith"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "login":"anne",
      "full_name":"Anne Steward"
   }
]
```

---

```
{
   "success":false,
   "    message":"Unknown login"
}
```

Because code does not know which message to expect, I have created two classes where UserList inherits from BaseResponse (an error message class). I have used inheritance, as all other methods like GetCarList, etc. are suitable of returning an error message as well. So no need to declare error fields multiple times. That had to be smart - I will always get or UserList fields or error message fields in the same object.

```
Public Class BaseResponse

    Public success As Boolean
    Public message As String

End Class


Public Class UserListResponse
    Inherits BaseResponse

    Public id As Integer
    Public login As String
    Public full_name As String

End Class
```

The problem is, that UserListResponse JSON message is an array, while ErrorMessage JSON is not an array. So deserialising will work when JSON will be UserList but will not work when JSON will be an error message:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of UserListResponse))(ReceivedJSONMessage)
```

Any ideas how to tackle this in smart way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that both of your return classes are working for deserializing the json correctly you just need in essence: "Am I a list or a string?" to ask for one path or the other.

**EDIT 8-30**
Okay so I missed that you do not KNOW till after it was executed, my bad.  You can do the logic inside of Sub Routine instead of a Function then that does the logic directly on examining a generic object passed instead.  Similar to this.

```
Private Sub DetermineReturn(obj As Object)
  If obj.GetType = GetType(String) Then
      Console.WriteLine(CType(obj, String))
    ElseIf obj.GetType = GetType(List(Of String)) Then
      CType(obj, List(Of String)).ForEach(Sub(x) Console.WriteLine(x))
    Else
      Console.WriteLine("UnKnOwN!1!")
    End If
End Sub


Sub Main()
  Dim testError = "Oh Shoot Error!"
  Dim GoodStuff = New List(Of String)({"I", "am", "a", "list"})

  Console.WriteLine("FirstExample")
  DetermineReturn(testError)
  Console.WriteLine()
  Console.WriteLine("SecondExample")
  DetermineReturn(GoodStuff)
  Console.WriteLine()
  Console.WriteLine("ThirdExample")
  DetermineReturn(1)

  Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Essentially You would just do the work of either transforming your JSON inside directly of the method 'DetermineReturn' instead of Console.WriteLines.  I am interpreting the 'obj' passed in, using reflection to get it's type, and then it is safe to be cast as that type.  So you would put the argument of your JSON return in the method like DetermineReturn((YourJSONResult)) and then inside the method do whatever transforms you need on the object.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand the approach. However I don't understand where shall I put my JSON to check "Am I a list or string" before trying to deserialise it. Can you provide me with another example with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject?

Comment: You would replace my 'ReturnString' method inside 'DetermineReturn' with the JSONConvert.DeserializeObject(Your API Call) for both.  You are essentially casting a return as a generic 'object'.  You just need to differentiate the input coming in to determine course of action.

Comment: Where shall I put my JSON message to determine the type it is. This message is String, so only at the moment of deserialisation we will know if JSON content could be deserialised into given type. So shall I do this like: Dim s = DetermineReturn(Of MyJSONString)?

In the meantime I have solved this trying to deserialise JSON message into UserListResponse (class without Inherits), once it fails I catch exception and then deserialise into BaseResponse. At the end I make a new class which combines both.

I don't like the way how I use exceptions, but I really do not understand your solution.

Comment: Let me write a slightly different updated example for your case that may tailor it better for your needs.

Comment: thanks for an update. I still think we didn't understand. You pass to testError and GoodStuff string or an array (.net types) where I just have a JSON message (always string before deserializing) which must be first deserialized and mapped to my .net complex type - just a class as in my original question). And here problem comes as depending on which JSON message it will be (1 of 2 expected), I need to deserialize it into different class (Business Object).

Comment: I guess in the simplest way I could think of it, is it should be possible to cast a string to an object and accept that.  To the best of my understanding of .NET, object, is one of the lowest level types and mostly every other type inherit from that.  So in essence a JSON is a string like "{  "id": 1,  "name": "A",     "tags": ["home", "away"] }.  You basically are casting a string down a level to an object and then it is simpler to deal with.  However if you still are needing to deserialize the JSON first, use something like .NET's Javascript deserializer to get the object first.